# Should Forms Auto Submit (Auto Advance) When Questions Are Correctly Filled In?

Tags: forms

Here's my form.

[image]

Now, I'm curious if I could remove the 'Continue' button and just have the form move to the next stage when someone correctly fills everything in.

This is a bit different than [When is an auto-saving form appropriate?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11448/when-is-an-auto-saving-form-appropriate)- because there's more questions to answer.

Here is another, similar, question but is a different context: 
[Auto Advance to Next Field](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22508/auto-advance-to-next-field)

Suggestions?

Comment: I would also say no. As mentioned that data entered may be valid but not necessarily correct. Users find some reassurance in reviewing forms like your example before hitting continue.

Comment: As a user, the absolute first thing I would do every single time is click "back" so I can look over everything and ensure I didn't make a mistake of some sort.  And if "back" didn't exist, I'd just close the page.  Not worth the hassle.

Comment: How do you know the questions are correctly filled in? Maybe the user spelled their name wrong. Maybe they entered the wrong email address. It is impossible for a computer to know if a form is "correctly" filled in. Users like to review forms before they click submit. Don't take that away from them.

Comment: @Izkata Could you elaborate on 'click back'? Do you mean back via the browser's back button or do you mean using a form's, own, back button.

Comment: @AlanKlement The form if it has one - but then again, I know enough about backend implementations not to trust the browser's back button when dealing with forms - it may or may not work correctly.

Comment: @Izkata I would go with these recommendations (one from Neilsen the other from Wroblewski) about forms having a back button: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7909/do-users-understand-the-browser-back-button & http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?571

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a difference between auto-saving and auto-advancing, so I wouldn't necessarily prescribe the benefits of one to the other in terms of user experience and usability.

The problem with auto-advancing is that you are removing control from the user.  Users like to feel like they are in control.  If the form starts to advance them through the workflow before they "feel" they are ready, they are going to feel a lack of control:

> Most flame wars you read about user interface issues focus on the wrong thing. Windows is better because it gives you more ways to resize the window. So what? That's missing the point. The point is, does the UI respond to the user in the way in which the user expected it to respond? If it didn't, the user is going to feel helpless and out of control, the same way I felt when the wheels of the dough bathtub didn't turn the way I pushed them, and I bumped into a wall. Bonk.
>
> UI is important because it affects the feelings, the emotions, and the mood of your users. If the UI is wrong and the user feels like they can't control your software, they literally won't be happy and they'll blame it on your software. If the UI is smart and things work the way the user expected them to work, they will be cheerful as they manage to accomplish small goals. Hey! I ripped a CD! It just worked! Nice software! Wooooooooooo!
>
> To make people happy, you have to let them feel like they are in control of their environment. To do this, you need to correctly interpret their actions. The interface needs to behave in the way they are expecting it to behave.
>
> Thus, the cardinal axiom of all user interface design:
>
> > **A user interface is well-designed when the program behaves exactly how the user thought it would.**
>
> As Hillel said, everything else is commentary. All the other rules of good UI design are just corollaries.

*Source: [Controlling Your Environment Makes You Happy
by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000057.html)*

The other problem beyond how the user feels about the experience is that you do not necessarily know that what the user entered is **correct**.  It may be *valid* according to your regular expressions and form validation, but it might not be what the user intends to enter.  If the form advances as soon as they have entered *valid* data you are taking away their ability to review to ensure it is *correct* data.

Giving them a button allows them the ability to review, plus it gives them the sense of control that they are using the form instead of the form using them.

Comment: Switched to this to the answer. Again, the user's anxiety is my #1 concern.

Comment: +1 for Hillel citation! Who knew, the old Jewish age knew about good UI, eh? :D...

Comment: "A user interface is well-designed when the program behaves exactly how the user thought it would." However there is a huge problem with this argumentation, because going by it we should go back to the old DOS UI's. It is by the hands of creative UI designers that we have gotten to the point where we are now and although in this explicit case for the reasons outlined I do believe it a bad idea to auto advance, one should never design purely based on user expectations.

Comment: @DavidMulder: That is not a correct interpretation of the quote.  The point is not to only stick to what has been done in the past.  The point is that an interface, even if new and creative, should be intuitive.  Similar to the saying "good design doesn't require a manual", which says nothing about designing to only what the user already knows.

Answer (score 24):

Bad idea, for at least 2 reasons

- you take away control from the user
- even if your validator says the fields are correct, the user might have made a typo somewhere and has no chance to see it before moving to next section

Comment: Good points, not being able to review answers might be an anxiety. If the questions were only radio buttons maybe....

Comment: I'll go with this b/c the most important concern I have is creating anxiety for the user - that can't be disputed.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with the accepted answer, that:

> - You take away control from the user
> - Even if your validator says the fields are correct, the user might have made a typo somewhere and has no chance to see it before moving to next section

Something else to note as well is that **the user will not always complete the form fields in order**.

In your example above, what happens if someone answers the radio buttons first because it takes one click, and fills in their name last? There is no foolproof way to ensure that someone has finished entering text into a text field, and leaves more questions than answers.

When would the form submit? When one character is entered? When the person tabs out of that field? If it submitted on tab out, what happens when a person leaves the cursor in the field while looking for the submit button?

While auto-validation and auto-saving work well, auto-submission is something that doesn't lend itself to being good UX.

Comment: "There is no foolproof way to ensure that someone has finished entering text into a text field, and leaves more questions than answers." Good point too.

Answer (score 5):

### Don't do this.

1. It doesn't make sense at all for many common form inputs. Any text
   fields or multi-select controls (checkbox lists, multi-select lists
   boxes), sliders, number spinners, or other free-form input simply
   doesn't have an obvious "done" state. Sure, you could make a regex
   that waits for a ".com" or ".edu" or ".org" or ".co.uk" or... at the
   end of an email text box, but...
2. It doesn't allow a user to process what they just typed into the
   input before it begins processing, so if they enter
   example@gmial.com they probably won't even have the time to see the
   typo before you advance the form. Even if you set a timer, you're
   going to have to set a timer that allows for the slowest
   hunt-and-peck typist to find their place and review what they
   entered.
3. All fields on your form must be required, of course. Because
   otherwise you can't tell if a field has not been filled out *yet* or
   will not be filled out.
4. What about people who like to review a form before they advance? You
   are actually punishing people who are trying to make sure the data
   they give you is correct.
5. Have you ever, **ever** seen a user be happy when a page turns
   without them hitting a button and telling it to do so? Would *you*
   be happy to be filling out a form and have it disappear while you
   are filling it out?
6. Along the same lines, users do not like when their expectations are
   violated. So, even IF all of the above were not true, even IF there
   were some benefit to doing this, you're going to be making users
   unhappy by doing things that they are not expecting you to do. With
   their data in the form, no less.

Best case scenario, you have a form with only dropdowns and radio buttons and you have users who do not make mistakes in answering or mousing (obviously a touch screen would be a nightmare), but at the same time have no prior expectations to how online data entry works. What benefit do you gain by taking the time/cost to implement this? One button click per page.

Answer (score 4):

I would say ***NO*** and here's why:

1. How would the ***form*** know ***if*** all the data was ***correct***?

   a. The ***form*** wouldn't, the ***user*** would, but a form ***could*** know if they were ***valid***.

   b. Users like to look things over to make sure everything is correct ***prior to continuing on***.
2. Based on the above, how would the ***form*** know ***when*** to auto-advance?

   a. The only way the form could know is if all fields were ***required***.
3. How would you get ***back*** to the prior step if you were continually auto-advancing?

Comment: The 'form may not be valid' point doesn't worry me, b/c having a submit button doesn't protect against invalid data entry. Your point 1b I agree with. The form would have every field required but you're correct if the form had optional parts. Going back doesn't worry me either b/c having a submit button doesn't denote going back either; they go back the same way whether it auto advances or not - either with a browser's back btn or add a link to go back.

Comment: My validity response was based off of your question title, *"Should Forms Auto Submit (Auto Advance) **When Questions Are Correctly Filled In**?"*. My guess is your wording is incorrect and that's not *really* what you meant to ask. You probably meant to ask, *"Should Forms Auto Submit (Auto Advance) **When All Questions Have Been Filled In**?"*.

Answer (score 3):

2 main UX problems I see:

1) Potential to tap on the wrong radio button on the last step, especially on mobile.

2) Also in Luke W's book he talks about how users enjoy reviewing a form briefly before clicking the continue/submit button. You'd remove their opportunity to do that.

Comment: Ahh mobile & mistype. Nice point.

Answer (score 1):

**No** you should not. Mechanisms like this have been abused in the past by programmers of malicious [dialers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialer):

[image: Dialer]

([source, a German Forum about computer fraud](http://forum.computerbetrug.de/threads/dialer-ok-fenster-aus-fachleute-sicht.9297/#post-115379))

Once the user entered the letters `OK` the dialer would connect to an expensive telephone number (it says 29 Euros per connection here) and the field would be locked in that state.

While those dialers are no longer seen in the wild today auto advancing forms may remind older people of those dialers.

Comment: Damn....that is sneaky...

Comment: @AlanKlement Well, fortunatly this is no longer possible as of broadband internet connections and the German laws made it very hard for those dialers in the end. But we learn: One really should read before pressing buttons and things!